# TypeError: Cannot read property 'startDate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having below error in my react component

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'startDate' of undefined
```

I know this is because I didn't bind my function. It works when I have `hour` in my `localStorage`. But now when I have `custom` in my `localStorage`.  And also it works in componentWillMount either it has `hour` or `custom`. So here is my code

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      filterType: this.getFilterType(localStorage.getItem('daysFilter') ? localStorage.getItem('daysFilter') : 'today'),
    }
  }
    getFilterType (type) {
    let filterType = 'hour'
    if (type === 'today') {
      filterType = 'hour'
    }
    if (type === "custom" ){
      const startDate = this.state.startDate
      const endDate   = this.state.endDate
    }
    return filterType
  }
}
```

But I need to know how can I bind my function inside constructor?

Comment: This is because `state` is not yet initialized.

Comment: you state don't have these values initially

Comment: And where you're setting the values for `state` ?

Comment: @SagarJajoriya Ok got it. So what is the solution for it?

Comment: @Harish Ok got it. So what is the solution for it?

Comment: @Profer you can use either destructuring with default value
`const {starDate = new Date(), endDate = new Date()} = this.state` or initialize in state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're instantiating `this.state` you are calling `getFilterType(type)` which uses `this.state` which is not yet initialized.